# Simpy synchronous communication channel

Tags: simpy

I'm a newbie starting to use Python and Simpy. I would like to have a **synchronous** communication channel between 2 processes. For example I would like to have:

```
channel = ...
def writer(env):
    for i in range(2):
        yield env.timeout(0.75)
        yield channel.put(i)
        print("produced {} at time {}".format(i, env.now)) 

def reader(env):
    while (True):
        yield env.timeout(1.2)
        i = yield channel.get()
        print("consumed {} at time {}".format(i, env.now))

env = simpy.Environment()
env.process(writer(env))
env.process(reader(env))
env.run()
```

It should give as a result:

```
produced 0 at time 1.2
consumed 0 at time 1.2
produced 1 at time 2.4
consumed 1 at time 2.4
```

What should I make/use for the definition of channel?

If I use a `Store` than I would get (slightly different from above):

```
import simpy
env = simpy.Environment()
channel = simpy.Store(env)

def writer():
    for i in range(2):
        yield env.timeout(0.75)
        yield channel.put(i)
        print("produced {} at time {}".format(i, env.now))   

def reader():
    while (True):
        yield env.timeout(1.2)
        i = yield channel.get()
        print("consumed {} at time {}".format(i, env.now))

env.process(writer())
env.process(reader())
env.run()
```

and the output would be:

```
produced 0 at time 0.75
consumed 0 at time 1.2
produced 1 at time 1.5
consumed 1 at time 2.4
```

But I should get as mentioned above. The writer should wait until the reader is ready to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not directly possible with the built-in resources.  A workaround might be the following:

```
import collections

import simpy


Message = collections.namedtuple('Message', 'received, value')


def writer(env, channel):
    for i in range(2):
        yield env.timeout(0.75)
        msg = Message(env.event(), i)
        yield channel.put(msg)
        yield msg.received
        print("produced {} at time {}".format(i, env.now))


def reader(env, channel):
    while (True):
        yield env.timeout(1.2)
        msg = yield channel.get()
        msg.received.succeed()
        print("consumed {} at time {}".format(msg.value, env.now))


env = simpy.Environment()
channel = simpy.Store(env, capacity=1)
env.process(writer(env, channel))
env.process(reader(env, channel))
env.run()
```

Output:

```
consumed 0 at time 1.2
produced 0 at time 1.2
consumed 1 at time 2.4
produced 1 at time 2.4
```

If you do the `print()` before `yield msg.received`, you’ll get:

```
produced 0 at time 0.75
consumed 0 at time 1.2
produced 1 at time 1.95
consumed 1 at time 2.4
```

The alternative would be to write your own resource type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But both the reader and writer process should wait on each other. This will not happen than, right? I guess the writer will continue although it should wait until the reader is ready to read.

Comment: Thank you very much. Basically this is what I need. I will now think about writing my own resource type. But first I have to learn more about Simpy and about Python in general. If you have any suggestions for the resource type I need, that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would continue using this until you feel more comforatble and familiar with Python and SimPy. Then, I would write a subclass of Store that does what you want. Also, read all of the SimPy docs. ;-)